# can't install woocommerce plugin on LOCALHOST

Tags: wordpress, plugins, localhost, woocommerce

can someone who has experience with wordpress help me??
I have been trying to install WooCommerce - excelling eCommerce plugin on my wordpress theme, but since I'm working on localhost I think this is causing me some problems. When I try to download it directly from wordpress dashboard it starts with the normal procedure and then it just stays like this and nothing happens: Downloading install package from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/woocommerce.2.1.12.zip…

while when I download the plugin separately and upload the .zip file in wordpress, I get this message: Are you sure you want to do this? Please try again.

when I click on Please try again, I get redirected in the step of choosing the file to upload and then if I do the same I get stuck on an infinite loop of doing the same things which lead me nowhere...

Comment: Since it is on localhost have you tried unzipping the file and copying the woocommerce folder into the plugins folder?

Comment: Thank you @Howlin, I just did it this way and the plugin showed up in wordpress plugins :)

Answer (score 16):

The solution to the problem is as follows:

- Download the plugin as .zip
- Unzip the .zip file
- Copy the plugin files to the plugins folder of Wordpress
- Open your Wordpress website and activate the plugin

Comment: Thank you so much sir.
I also had this problem. I have solved the problem in the way you have shown.